# battery using zinc, copper, and vinegar

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox, analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

I filed one side of a penny to reveal the zinc; then I bent the coin and dropped it into a cup of white vinegar. Shortly afterward, many tiny bubbles were forming on the zinc side. Later on, I noticed a black residue on the zinc side. What might be the reaction that occurred? *[I believe that the gas was either H2 or CO2 gas. I also believe that the black residue was either CuO  or carbon]* **{Zn + Cu + H ion + CH3COO ion --> ???}**

Comment: The zinc reacted with the acetic acid in vinegar, with hydrogen gas being evolved. The black stuff is not carbon or CuO. Just some kind of crud.

Answer (score 0):

Copper surface was probably a little bit oxidized into $\ce{CuO}$. Dipped into vinegar, this oxide is quickly dissolved by the acetic acid, producing $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ ions in solution $$\ce{CuO  +  2 CH3COOH  -> Cu^{2+}  + 2 CH3COO^-}$$Then, zinc may react with these copper ions, producing copper metal which looks black if the dimensions of the grains are small enough.
$$\ce{Cu^{2+} + Zn ⟶ Cu + Zn^{2+}}$$

Comment: Thank you, Maurice.